# Android + Facebook SDK + "message" property is now ignored?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm learning the FB api and I need assistance with one issue.  I'm attempting to prepopulate the message with data from my application.  Seems the message property is now ignored.  Can some offer me a solution to this issue?  I've read somewhere that creating your own dialog and using facebook.request(path, bundleWithMessage, "POST"); would do the trick.  Can someone post a snippet for me to see?  I'm researching the docs, but don't see examples, and I'm not sure what path refers too, assuming the graph-api.  Sorry for the noob question, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On July 12, we are ignoring the message parameter in Feed Dialogs. This eliminates the ability to pre-fill stream stories (prohibited by Policy IV.2).

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/